# Value of type 'any?' had no member 'valueForKey' - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, facebook-login

I'm getting this error,

> "Value of type 'any?' had no member 'valueForKey'", for userName, fbID, email and fbLink when compiling.

```
func returnUserDatafromFBGraphRequest(withAuthUID uid: String){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(normal), link"]).start( completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {

            //process error

            print("[LoginControl] Error FBSDKgraph request \(error?.localizedDescription)")

        } else {



            // successful request, do work

            let userName = result.valueForKey("name") as! String

            let fbID = result.valueForKey("id") as! String

            let email = result.valueForKey("email") as! String

            let fbLink = result.valueForKey("link") as! String

            guard let picture = result.valueForKey("picture") as? NSDictionary,
            let pictureData = picture.valueForKey("data") as? NSDictionary,
            let pictureURL = pictureData.valueForKey("url") as? String else {
                print("[LoginControl] Error getting fb pic url")
                return

            }

            print("[LoginControl] fetched user from fb: \(email)")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast `Any` in to something more meaningful something like `[String:Any]`

```
   guard let fbData = result as? [String:Any] else { return }

   let fbid = fbData["id"]
   let email = fbData["email"]
```